# iPhone how to get the sender email address while passing the file from mail app to my own iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Is there any way to get a sender email address while passing the  file from mail app to my own ios app?

When I tap the file in mail app I can import that file into my own app if that file format supported by my ios app. At this time is it possible to pass the sender email address also into my iphone app?

Answer (score 2):

No, that information is not available to your app.